# Android filter preferences (mutual exclusion)

Tags: android, filter, preferences

I have 2 list preferences in my app's preferences.  I would like to filter one based on a selection from the other making them mutually exclusive.  For example, Pref1 and Pref2 both have A,B,C, and D.  If A is selected in Pref1, I want it to be hidden/disabled when I go in to Pref2.  I can disable the entire preference with an onChange event, but I can't figure out how I can instead drill into the list's items and deactivate one of the list items.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a `MultiSelectListPreference`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help.  I have (need) 2 independent preference lists.